# Android's BroadcastReceiver not called in GCM

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

Currently I'm creating an application that supports chatting between users using GCM, everything is working fine except that when i click on the message received via a notification, the chat activity opens with null data.

I've registered the GCM broadcast receiver in the manifest as follows:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="xxx.xxx.xxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And on the chat activity, I have something like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

            String message = b.getString("message");

            Log.i(TAG, " Received in Activity " + message + ", NAME = "
                    + chattingToName + ", dev ID = " + chattingToDeviceID);

            // this demo this is the same device
            ChatPeople curChatObj = addToChat(chattingToName, message,
                    "Received");
            addToDB(curChatObj); // adding to db

            populateChatMessages();

        }
    };
```

I guess this part is not called since on the chat history is not updated with the received message.

Any idea guys?

Thanks in advance.

This is my GcmBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Intent i = new Intent("CHAT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED");
        i.putExtra("message", extras.getString("message"));

        context.sendBroadcast(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: So what does your `GcmBroadcastReceiver` do? That is what will be called when you get a new message - not any `BroadcastReceiver` registered in your activity.

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you added that to your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. Added to the question

Comment: If you're GcmBroadcastReceiver is being called (i.e., that log statement is being printed), then it doesn't seem the problem has anything to do with GCM but instead with your `addToChat()`, 'addToDB()' or 'populateChatMessages()` steps. Or am I misunderstanding and your `GcmBroadcastReceiver` is not actually being called?

Comment: GcmBroadcastReceiver is not being called at all. The logcat doesn't show this log. :/

Comment: The code you posted for your GcmBroadcastReceiver is still a programmatically created `BroadcastReceiver` - can you correct it with the `GcmBroadcastReceiver` class you have listed in your manifest?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand what you mean. How can i correct it?

Comment: When you call `gcm.register(SENDER_ID)`, do you get a registration id back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you are not handling the User Notification received from the chat app in the correct manner. Please take a look at this official Google Documentation that deals with the [User Notification on GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html).

Also please take a look at this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/) that has code for the chat application.

Hope that Helps!!